# SQL Azure delayed response every 10 seconds

Tags: c#, sql, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

We're running several Azure web apps (.NET Core, MVC4, MVC5) against SQL Azure. Every 10 seconds, there is a considerable delay in response from the SQL server. We have tested this using a console app looping the same query 100 times, and regardless of when we start the console app, the delay happens exactly every 10 seconds.

The query typically takes 150ms to complete. Every 10 seconds it will take 2-3 seconds.

The behaviour is the same on both test and production DB servers. We are using a few triggers (5), none of which are triggered by the query used in the load test.

The load test is a stored procedure with a simple select query. There are no other users using our test environment while we're running these tests.

We have also load tested this using the Performance test tool in Azure portal, with the same results.

Any ideas on where to begin looking for the underlying cause of this delay?

Our test code:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ss = new Stopwatch();
        // Let's go
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ss.Restart();
                connection.Open();
                var sql = "EXEC usp_loadTestSp";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Current time {i}: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine($"Loop time {i}: {ss.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
            }
        }

        EndApp();
    }
```

**Update:**
Just created a new SQL server with a new, blank SQL database on Azure. No tables, no nothing. Updated connection string in test app, changed query to `SELECT NULL`. Same result, it takes a lot longer once every 10 seconds...

Comment: Have you tried increasing the SQL instances DTU?

Comment: `Every 10 seconds it will take 2-3 seconds.` What is the value of `i` at the start of the 2-3 seconds. At the end? Is that reproducible (i.e. could it be related to the number of iterations rather than the time window)?

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes. The behavior is the same on the test db (50 DTUs) and prod db (500 DTUs Premium).

Comment: What's the garbage collector doing?

Comment: @mjwills The value of `i` when the delay happens will vary for each time the test app is run. But the delay **always** occurs at UtcNow ending with 9 - i.e. at 9, 19, 29 etc seconds of every minute. This is regardless of when I start the test app, and regardless of how many iterations are run.

We tried adding `Thread.Sleep(500);` on each iteration. The behavior is the same, the delay comes when UtcNow seconds is x9.

Comment: @MikeMiller No garbage collection occurs during 100 iterations in the test app

Comment: Any backups running, although that would be super frequent.

Comment: Might be worth posting usp_loadTestSp if it's not proprietary.  Be interesting to see if its reproducible.

Comment: @MikeMiller No backups running at this time. 

usp_loadTestSp is proprietary, but _super_ simple. Just `SELECT Id, ProductName, Price FROM Products WHERE Id = @ProductId`

Comment: Sorry chap, I'm out of ideas.  I guess you've checked to see if the Azure performance tuner has any ideas?  Is sys.resource_stats granular enough to identify that the issue is definitely on the SQL end?

Comment: Where exactly are you running the console app? FWIW, I couldn't repro the problem with your code.

Comment: Interesting @DanGuzman, thanks. We have run this test both on localhost and on an Azure Web App instance with the same results. Both are running against the same Azure SQL db.

Comment: @mjwills Gotcha :) Inverted it now, running _only_ in the pitfall second. Slow every time...

Worth noting that the pitfall second seems to be "moving". It was ending with 9 before, now it's ending with 2. Suggesting that the cycle we're looking at is something like 10.x seconds.

Comment: @mjwills `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm` was true. We tried setting it to false, same behavior as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for replying and sorry for the delayed answer.

I have found the cause of this issue, and it has nothing to do with SQL Azure or any other Azure service.

The issue was local on my device, and the culprit was the Google Drive Stream client which I use to sync my documents to Google Drive. Testing using "ping -t", I get a very steady delay of 2 seconds every 10 seconds. Disabling Google Drive Stream, the ping is fast all the time. Re-enable Google Drive Stream, and the delay is back.

Now onto finding out how to keep using file stream without delays.

TGM

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific reason SQL Azure would behave this way generally.  However, when you see situations like this, I would recommend that you separate the client side logic and client driver/network from the logic happening on the server first.  So, in this case, you might create a stored procedure that does the equivalent of your loop in your program and try to run that on the server and time things.  It should give you some data without these other pieces involved.

Your other option is to look at the query store (which will give you summary data of the execution time on the server for queries, not trace-level data, but it gives you min/max/last/avg/stdev for each metric).  This should give you another data point to evaluate whether this is from the server side or the client/app side.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017

Another option is to enable set "statistics time on" for executing your queries - this would give you an additional set of data you can retrieve in the client driver about how many resources the server used to process your query.

One possible reason for your issue is if you had skew in the data on the server - in other words, if you have far more 10s in the table than other values.  You would have to retrieve more values in this case and that could introduce variance into the query response time.

Finally, you can use XEvents to trace the execution time of each query (though this requires a bit of work to set up currently on SQL Azure, it is possible to dump out an event trace of the queries to blob storage so you can review how much time the server thinks it is using).

I hope that gives you a few things to try to track down your mystery.